# Getting 2 values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object

I would like to select an item from the dropdown list and would like to set the state of staffId to it. I would like dropdown to show the name, but after I select the name, set the staffid to state. I would also like to achieve this without hardcoding the values in an if-else loop as I have thousands of data to work with.

This is the data fetched from WebAPI and stored in a state called items

```
this.setState({
    items: dataSource
  staffId: ''
})
```

This state of items will be this.

```
[
    {"departmentName":"HOUSE","employeeName":"TEST1", "staffId" : "00001"},
    {"departmentName":"HOUSE","employeeName":"TEST2", "staffId" : "00002"},
    {"departmentName":"HOUSE","employeeName":"TEST3", "staffId" : "00003"}
]
```

I have created a dropdown in react native with just the emplyeeName. I am using react-native-material-dropdown for the library. I would like to show employeeName but when a user select a name, get an id instead

```
let staff = this.state.listOfEmployees.map(item => ({
        value: item.employeeName
        staffId: item.staffId
      }));
```

```
<Dropdown
    label='Staff Name'
    baseColor='#0079b5'
    data={staff}
    selectedValue={value}
    onChangeText={(staffId) => this.onChangeName(staffId)}
/>
```

Here in this function, I would like to set the state of staffId to the staffId of the selected value.

```
onChangeName = (staffId) => {
    //set the state of staffId to the staffId of the selected value.
    //For Example, if AUNG THU 1 is selected, the state of staffId is '00001'.
    this.setState({
       staffId: staffId
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `valueExtractor` and `labelExtractor` props. Should look something like this:

```
<Dropdown
  label='Staff Name'
  baseColor='#0079b5'
  data={staff}
  selectedValue={value}
  valueExtractor={({ staffId }) => staffId}
  labelExtractor={({ employeeName }) => employeeName}
  onChangeText={(staffId) => this.onChangeName(staffId)}
/>
```