# CefSharp 'CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame' false after page loaded async

Tags: winforms, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

I found error while using [LoadPageAsync Method](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/79/CefSharp.OffScreen.Example/Program.cs#L117).
All code to reproduce is below.

1) Wait while `new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com/")` page loaded.

2) then press `button1`.
 Result: `canExecuteJs` will be `false` while `canExecuteJs1` will be `true`.

In other hand if don't wait for `new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com/")` page to be loaded, and in moment button appear on screen click it, both variables will be `true`.

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
    Cef.Initialize(settings);

    chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com/");

    Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
    chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}

public Task LoadPageAsync(IWebBrowser browser, string address = null)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
    EventHandler<LoadingStateChangedEventArgs> handler = null;
    handler = (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (!args.IsLoading)
        {
            browser.LoadingStateChanged -= handler;
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }
    };

    browser.LoadingStateChanged += handler;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
        browser.Load(address);
    return tcs.Task;
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await LoadPageAsync(chromeBrowser, "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862329/wordpress-submit-form-into-new-tab-and-continue-processing");
   var canExecuteJs = chromeBrowser.CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame; //FALSE
   await LoadPageAsync(chromeBrowser, "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59861819/getting-2-values-from-array-of-objects");
   var canExecuteJs1 = chromeBrowser.CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame; //TRUE
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example,  I'll have a look

Comment: I've created https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3021 it may be that we'll end up removing CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame as it's unreliable now.

Comment: @amaitland. Just to let you know that  executing of javaScript also failing while this prop is false.

Comment: You'd need to execute the javascript directly on the frame to avoid the check.